# KVO on bool property, not invoke observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: ios, singleton, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I have an appDelegate, that has a property myWindow of MyWindowClass. I need observe bool property from myWindow. Than I have a CustomViewController, that needs to observe for bool value changes. 
If I want to addObserver I do following in ViewController:

```
LayerWindow *w = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window;
    [w addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"touchInsideLayerWindow" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];
```

In ViewController I have

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

method defined, also in header file.

In WindowClass I have following code:

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]forKey:@"touchInsideLayerWindow"];
 NSLog(@"isTouchInside %@", self.touchInsideLayerWindow ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Method observeValueForKeyPath in ViewController is never called. Does anyone know, what is wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looks like one problem is that you said the property is a `BOOL`, but you are trying to set it to an `NSNumber` in the `setValue` call.

Second:  if you make your setter with `@synthesize`, then KVO is automatically supported as long as you use dot-syntax.

```
   self.touchInsideLayerWindow = YES;
```

Comment: Well Iam aware of that, but I didn't find any other way, how to set value of bool, because it isnt Object...

Comment: I've used dot syntax even before the solution that I have currently, but that didn't work either. :(

Comment: as says @sellers, using `@synthesize` provides automatic support for KVO

Answer (score 0):

replace this line `[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]forKey:@"touchInsideLayerWindow"];` with

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"touchInsideLayerWindow"];
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]forKey:@"touchInsideLayerWindow"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"touchInsideLayerWindow"];
```

Comment: Well, this changes nothing, because basically is the same code as mine, speaking in general.

Comment: yes its basically the same, without hte `willChange` and `didChange` calls :). Try adding these two too

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, code for KVO was correct, error was elsewhere. I was calling addObserver on object, that was not properly initialised.